# How to replace compound primary key in table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "PostViews"
(
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "PostId" integer NOT NULL,
  "UserId" integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PostViews_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("PostId", "UserId"),
  CONSTRAINT "PostViews_PostId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("PostId")
      REFERENCES "Posts" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT "PostViews_UserId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("UserId")
      REFERENCES "Users" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

It is join-through table which links many `Users` to many `Posts` with compound pk `PostId,UserId`. What I have to do is to drop uniqueness from `PostId,UserId` in order to allow to store more than one `PostView` per post per user.

1. Should I remove pk and add index for `PostId,UserId` (or add index first and then drop pk)?
2. Or Should I add `id serial` column, make it pk and then drop compound pk?

Comment: I would drop the old PK and add a new one. perhaps `("PostId", "UserId","createdAt")`

Comment: I thought about it but if user will browse page (my app is a web app) on 2 PCs and try to create post view at the same time there will be error...

Comment: but what's the chance they'll be ynchronised to within 1 microsecond (i millisecond on windows) they'll get an error and hit refresh and al will be good.

Comment: Does this table need a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not explain the `updatedAt` column purpose so I would drop it, rename the `createdAt` as `viewedAt` and make it part of the PK:

```
constraint PostViews_pkey PRIMARY KEY (PostId, UserId, viewedAt)
```

The chance of the user viewing the post twice at the exact same time is insignificant. If you want to provide for that case then wrap the client insertion code in a `try/catch` and retry in case of a PK exception.

Do not use double quotes for identifiers. It will be a real pain forever.

Comment: Are you sure it is a good practise making try/catch? Why not to add id column as PK? As for the quotes - how I can use single quotes in `Postgres`? It throws syntax error when I try to use single quotes instead of double - I thought that only double quotes work in PG...

Comment: I get the feeling `createdAt` and `updatedAt` may be audit columns with names consistent across many tables that all share the same audit triggers

Comment: @user606521 My mistake. There are no single quotes for identifiers. Just leave them without quotes at all. Edited the answer

Comment: @user606521 If you do not use a `try/catch` you risk having an uncaught exception reaching the user.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto - if there are capital letters in column/table/etc names Postgres they must be enclosed with double quotes like `"PostId"` - otherwise they will be transformed to lower case `postid` and there will be error due not exitant column. `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns are automatically created by ORM for every table. Yes I know - but after try catch there might be another error and in theory it may never succeed - I am asking if this is normal/common practise if such situation is very unlikely to happen?